# how to link two many to many eloquent laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, relationship

I have 3 models -
Student
Course
Lecturer

There are two many-to-many relationships -
StudentCourse (students registering for many courses)
CourseLecturer (many lecturers assigned to many courses)

How can I retrieve the lecturer assigned to a course from studentcourse model

Comment: your StudentCourse model is a pivot model?

Comment: No. Will that help?

Comment: Not that it helps, but your question asked how to retrieve lecturer from StudentCourse model. So just want to know whether you really want from StudentCourse model.